# Different Output in MacOS Terminal vs Xcode (C program)

Tags: c, xcode, terminal, output

Having output issues with terminal vs Xcode. Grateful to anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Simple program:

```
/* Military officer: age, rank, serial number, base pay, and number of years in service */

 #include < stdio.h>

int main()

{

int age, rank, ss1, ss2, ss3;

float base_pay, years;

    /* Ask User to Input Various Entries */

    printf("Enter officer age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Enter officer rank (e.g. 3 for captain): ");
    scanf("%d", &rank);

    printf("Enter serial number (e.g. 000-00-0000): ");
    scanf("%d -%d -%d", &ss1, &ss2, &ss3);

    printf("Enter base pay: ");
    scanf("%f", &base_pay);

    printf("Enter number of years in service: ");
    scanf("%f", &years);

    /* Output of Entries */

    printf("\nOfficer\t\t\tOfficer\t\t\tSerial\t\t\tBase\t\tYears\n");
    printf("Age\t\t\tRank\t\t\tNumber\t\t\tPay\t\tin\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(USD)\t\tService\n\n");
    printf("=======\t\t\t=======\t\t\t===========\t\t=========\t=======\n\n");

    printf("%-d\t\t\tO-%-d\t\t\t%-.3d-%.2d-%.4d\t\t$%-.2f\t%-10.1f\n\n", age, rank, ss1, ss2, ss3, base_pay, years);

    return 0;
}
```

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XsmE.png)

[XCode Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QccLU.png)

Comment: when calling any for the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the tab stops are not being used in the 'XCode output' rather it is just spacing over 8 spaces.   Can the tab stops be set in 'XCode'?

Comment: Don't use tabs, use spaces. The `printf` format specifiers allow to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

May be "\t" behavior is different between them.

Answer (score 0):

The output issues are caused because the print format (too many \t occurrences) is pretty error prone, although it looks good. I would suggest sacrificing some aesthetics and simply printing the attribute name followed by its value, like this:

```
 printf("Age: %d\n", age);
```

Followed by the others.